# Create a self-signed certificate to exchange SSL in W2003 SB

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, exchange, migration, certificate

I'm doing a migration of some accounts in a local exchange server (W2003 server SB). Because of a limitation of O365 that seems to need SSL 993 connection to perform the IMAP migration, i need to enable SSL on my exchange server.

We have not certificate. I'm trying to make a self-signed certificate but apparently, W2003 SB does not have certificate services.

In the same LAN i have a w2k8 standard that i think it has certificate services. The question is: ¿Can i use a certificate created in the w2k8 machine for my exchange server in the w2003 machine? If yes, ¿how can i do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a toolkit for IIS 6 named Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Resource Kit Tools that can be download from Microsoft downloads page. Inside of it there is a tool named SelfSSL.exe than can be used to create the certificate. It's quite easy. 
I assigned the certificate to the IMAP server and restarted the service, now everything works OK.